# How to use ExoPlayer in Android

Tags: android

In my application I want use **exoplayer** to play video and for this I added this dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.0'
```

with simple way I can play video with this code:

```
player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
binding.player.player = player

// Build the media item.
val mediaItem: MediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(url)
// Set the media item to be played.
player.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
// Prepare the player.
player.prepare()
// Start the playback.
player.play()
```

But I want **add Header** for video and for this I write below codes:

```
val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DataSource.Factory {
    val dataSource: HttpDataSource = httpDataSourceFactory.createDataSource()
    // Set a custom authentication request header.
    dataSource.setRequestProperty("Header", "Value")
    dataSource
}
```

But in my code not found `httpDataSourceFactory`. 
I used this link tutorial : https://exoplayer.dev/customization.html#customizing-server-interactions

How can I add **header** for exoplayer?

Answer (score 2):

```
 val dataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
            .setDefaultRequestProperties(hashMapOf("Header" to "Value"))
 val audioSource: MediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
```

Use the "DefaultHttpDataSource"

Comment: Please check your token.

Here is the server-side response:

{
    "success": false,
    "data": {
        "error": "احراز هویت شما انجام نشد"
    },
    "message": "شرمنده، خطایی در سیستم رخ داده!"
}

Comment: Thanks my friend. Do you add Authorization token in header?

Comment: Can you test this with PostMan? please. Really I need this. Thanks

Comment: Yep the response was try with PostMan

Comment: Yes with PostMan is ok. But how can I used this in exoplayer ? can you help me?

Comment: Can you help me my friend or not?